# Remove empty array/List from JSON request string

Tags: vb.net, json.net

How can I remove empty array and empty list from a JSON string?

I use vb.net and json.net to make this but json.net can't remove empty array from JSON string. My JSON string is like this:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "token": "tikenname",
    "method": "task.run",
    "params": {
        "commandList": [{
            "method": "Users.new",
            "params": {
                "userIds": "userid",
                "details": {
                    "credentials": {
                        "userName": "user",
                        "password": "pass"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "rights": {},
                        "quota": {
                            "daily": {
                                "limit": {}
                            },
                            "weekly": {
                                "limit": {}
                            },
                            "monthly": {
                                "limit": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "wwwFilter": {}
                    },
                    "autoLogin": {
                        "addresses": {},
                        "addressGroup": {}
                    },
                    "vpnAddress": {},
                    "groups": {}
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "method": "set.save"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

for example I want to remove this section from my string

```
                    "data": {
                        "rights": {},
                        "quota": {
                            "daily": {
                                "limit": {}
                            },
                            "weekly": {
                                "limit": {}
                            },
                            "monthly": {
                                "limit": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "wwwFilter": {}
                    },
                    "autoLogin": {
                        "addresses": {},
                        "addressGroup": {}
                    },
                    "vpnAddress": {},
                    "groups": {}
```

And here's my class:

```
Public Class Account
    Public Property jsonrpc As String
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property token As String
    Public Property method As String
    Public Property params As New AccountSetParams
End Class

Public Class AccountSetParams
    Public Property commandList As New List(Of AccountSetCommandlist)
End Class

Public Class AccountSetCommandlist
    Public Property method As String
    Public Property params As New AccountSetUserDetails
End Class

Public Class AccountSetUserDetails
    Public Property userIds() As String
    Public Property details As New AccountSetDetails
    Public Property domainId As String
End Class

Public Class AccountSetDetails 
    Public Property credentials As New AccountSetCredentials 
    Public Property fullName As String 
    Public Property data As New AccountSetData 
    Public Property autoLogin As New AccountSetAutologin 
    Public Property vpnAddress As New AccountSetVpnaddress 
    Public Property groups() As New AccountSetGroup 
End Class
...
```

Comment: i try required value and ignore value but its dos not work for this problem. also i set `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore ` and `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` . empty array still visible in JSON string

Comment: What does your `AccountSetDetails` class look like?

Comment: `Public Class AccountSetDetails`
        `Public Property credentials As New AccountSetCredentials`
        `Public Property fullName As String`
        `Public Property data As New AccountSetData`
        `Public Property autoLogin As New AccountSetAutologin`
        `Public Property vpnAddress As New AccountSetVpnaddress`
        `Public Property groups() As New AccountSetGroup`
    `End Class` Other classes are also similar

Comment: To clarify, do you always want the specific JSON section you highlighted to be excluded from the output regardless of what is in it, or are you saying that you want to exclude ANY part of the output that has an empty list or array, not specifically that section?

Comment: all i need is that remove all empty list and empty array from output Json string with any name. that section was a example and not created all tmie. i use some other type too and they have different type and value name

Comment: I was thinking about this today and you could convert the data as before with the unwanted JSON elements then use JSON to LINQ to filter out any unwanted elements. The other option is assemble the JSON yourself using methods like in blog post http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing. I just think its possible to get what you want using the base serializer but you should be able to build your own.

Comment: I believe I found a way by traversing the document looking for JArray with no children then deleting them by I am still working on the particulars.  This is an interesting problem.

Comment: i am new in programing and i dont know how i can do this . can you send code snippet ?

Comment: This is tricky I thought I had it but I think it would be easier to have to custom logic would map your objects over to another set of DTOs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx then serialize those objects.  There is a library called automapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/ that could help make coping data from one set of objects to another. Since you said you are new to programming I would also suggest a project that I happen to use called being the worst at http://beingtheworst.com.  I think it will help.

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like Json.Net provides an easy way to exclude empty lists or arrays like you are describing.  Technically, most of the objects that you want to exclude are NOT empty: they contain other objects [that contain other objects ...] that are empty.

So to accomplish this, you will need to use recursive descent to filter out the "non-useful" information.  I think probably the best approach is to first load your object graph into a `JObject` (or `JArray`), then recursively copy non-empty elements into a new `JObject` (or `JArray`), working your way from the deepest levels upward.  You can then serialize the copy to get the pared-down JSON you want.  This approach will allow you to handle any object structure in a generic manner.

Here is a function that should do the trick:

```
Function RemoveEmptyChildren(token As JToken) As JToken

    If token.Type = JTokenType.Object Then

        Dim copy As JObject = New JObject()

        For Each prop As JProperty In token.Children(Of JProperty)()

            Dim child As JToken = prop.Value
            If child.HasValues Then
                child = RemoveEmptyChildren(child)
            End If

            If Not IsEmpty(child) Then
                copy.Add(prop.Name, child)
            End If

        Next

        Return copy

    ElseIf token.Type = JTokenType.Array Then

        Dim copy As JArray = New JArray()

        For Each child As JToken In token.Children()

            If child.HasValues Then
                child = RemoveEmptyChildren(child)
            End If

            If Not IsEmpty(child) Then
                copy.Add(child)
            End If

        Next

        Return copy

    End If

    Return token

End Function

Function IsEmpty(token As JToken) As Boolean

    Return (token.Type = JTokenType.Array And Not token.HasValues) Or
           (token.Type = JTokenType.Object And Not token.HasValues) Or
           (token.Type = JTokenType.String And token.ToString() = String.Empty) Or
           (token.Type = JTokenType.Null)

End Function
```

Here is a short example demonstrating how to use the function:

```
Dim jsonString As String = _
    "{" + _
        """Int"" : 1," + _
        """String"" : ""Foo""," + _
        """EmptyString"" : """"," + _
        """EmptyArray"" : []," + _
        """EmptyObject"" : {}," + _
        """NullValue"" : null," + _
        """ArrayOfEmptyChildren"" : [ [], {}, """", null ]," + _
        """ChildObjectWithEmptyValues"" : {" + _
            """Array"" : []," + _
            """Object"" : {}," + _
            """Null"" : null," + _
            """String"" : """"" + _
        "}," + _
        """Boolean"" : true" + _
    "}"

Dim token As JToken = RemoveEmptyChildren(JToken.Parse(jsonString))

Console.WriteLine(token.ToString(Formatting.Indented))
```

And here is the output of the above example.  Notice that only the non-empty information remains.

```
{
  "Int": 1,
  "String": "Foo",
  "Boolean": true
}
```

Note: if you are starting from an object instead of a JSON string, you can still use this function.  Just replace `JToken.Parse(jsonString)` in the example above with `JToken.FromObject(yourObject)`.

Also, if you want to change what gets removed or doesn't get removed from the output, you can modify the `IsEmpty` function to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.